# Xamarin.Forms: ListView and horizontal swiping

Tags: listview, scroll, xamarin.forms

I need to incorporate a Xamarin.Forms.ListView control (with vertical scrolling) in a layout with multiple views next to each other where I could swipe horizontally to move from one of the views to another one. I have a control based on the “ScrollView” control that scrolls horizontally, but, at least on Android 5 or 6, if I put a ListView into it, then all swiping movements on the ListView that are not perfectly vertical cause the outer control to scroll horizontally and not the ListView to scroll vertically. Therefore I need to solve a complaint that it is too difficult to scroll in the ListView. The user is likely to make swipes that differ by a small angle from the vertical direction. How can I make swipes that are not perfectly vertical but still rather vertical than horizontal cause the ListView to scroll? You might tell me something like “Do not put a ListView in a ScrollView”, but I know about a mobile application where it is possible to change views by horizontal swiping and also to scroll vertically within some of these views, and I need it to be possible to navigate in my application the same way.